# ANTLR4 latest version that can use C++14

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to compile the C++ code generated by ANTLR 4.10.1 for a simple grammar but I'm getting this error:

```
ANTLRInputStream.h:32:39: error: expected ')' before 'input' ANTLRInputStream(std::string_view input);
```

from what I can see, `std::string_view` was introduced in the C++17 standard. The compiler we use supports up to C++14, and from some google search I saw that ANTLR 4.7 can use C++14, but I was wondering how can I find out the latest ANTLR 4 version that produces C++ code that can be compiled with C++14 standard (to get most updated ANTLR fixes/functionality I can).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to get the git repo from Github and check the file history for `runtime/cpp/CMakeLists.tx`. Go back until you find the switch to C++17.

Alternatively: build the runtime yourself and revert the changes for C++17. This will also give you the latest fixes and improvements (unless they require C++17).

Comment: Thanks. Found it in the repo notes. ( [C++] Bump minimum required version to C++17 (target:cpp) ) 4.10